Sorting React Table by Date-Time in Ascending Order Doesn't Work Correctly
I'm working on a React application where I have a table displaying data that includes date and time fields. The date format in my data is YYYY/MM/DD, and I concatenate it with the time to create a complete datetime string for comparison.
Problem:
I'm trying to sort my table rows so that the newest date-time combinations appear at the top, but the sorting doesn't seem to work correctly. Instead, the newest records still end up on top of the table.
Here's the relevant part of my sorting logic in the React component:
const sortedDataForms = [...dataForms].sort((a, b) => {
  const isoDateA = a.date.split('/').reverse().join('-');
  const isoDateB = b.date.split('/').reverse().join('-');
  const datetimeA = new Date(`${isoDateA}T${a.time}`);
  const datetimeB = new Date(`${isoDateB}T${b.time}`);
  return datetimeB - datetimeA;
});

I've ensured that the date and time formats are consistent (YYYY/MM/DD for date and HH:mm:ss for time). Despite this, the sorting order remains incorrect.

Omit the reverse, because Date expects the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.

Yeah thats true but in isoDateA, isoDateB i make it to a YYYY-MM-DD. You want me to store it as YYYY-MM-DD from the beginning?

No, you must convert a.date = "YYYY/MM/DD" to isoDateA = "YYYY-MM-DD". This requires no reverse().

I made a function for converting the date, now the data is sorted by the time but not the date.
  const convertDate = (dateString) => {
    const [year, month, day] = dateString.split('/');
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  };

  const sortedDataForms = [...dataForms].sort((a, b) => {

    const isoDateA = convertDate(a.date);
    const isoDateB = convertDate(b.date);

    const datetimeA = new Date(`${isoDateA}T${a.time}`);
    const datetimeB = new Date(`${isoDateB}T${b.time}`);

    return datetimeB - datetimeA;
  });


One more thing: You need return datetimeA - datetimeB because you must return a negative number if A comes before B.

It doesn't really work, when i change the return the time is no longer sorted by time. I think i have some bug when i store the time/date or somthing.

I hope this simple example makes clear what I wanted to say in the comments:


console.log([{
    date: "2024/01/01",
    time: "10:00:00"
  }, {
    date: "2023/01/01",
    time: "11:00:00"
  }]
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(`${a.date.replaceAll("/","-")}T${a.time}`) - new Date(`${b.date.replaceAll("/","-")}T${b.time}`);
  }));



